# Where to find individual pages in Concrete5?

Tags: concrete5

I'm not a web developer, but I've ended up trying to fix a website for a friend of a friend, you know how these things go..

Anyway I've used Wordpress a lot but the guys site is on Concrete5 which I've never used.

I've got it all working locally and made a copy of the theme in case I break anything.

I can't seem to find the individual pages. I have all the templates, full.php etc. But if I want to find the contact us page, where would I find that? I can't seem to find it in any of the folders.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How does Concrete5 arrange it's absolute paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220431/how-does-concrete5-arrange-its-absolute-paths)

> Short answer: All page requests are actually going through the one and
>   only index.php file. Page content is stored in the database, not in
>   files on the server.

This makes a lot of sense considering it's a CMS.